# LINQ - loading data from tables with circular references

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the below tables where the StationAvailableMoves.StationID and StationAvailableMoves.AvailableNextStationID both have relationships on the Station.ID column.

I am using this to control a process from from station object to station object where on station can have multiple routes.

[image]

When I then import those tables into the Entity Framework model I get the below circular reference table.

[image]

I am then trying to load the data in the below DTO

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Namespace Models

    <DataContract()>
    Public Class Stations

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property ID As Int32

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property Name As String

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property BullName As String

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property StationMoves As IList(Of Stations)

    End Class

End Namespace
```

While I can load the data into the primitives types, with the below LINQ query, I am not sure how the then load the child objects which are coming over in the call.

```
    Using db As New StockTrackingEntities

        Dim var = (From s In db.Stations.Where(Function(w) w.BUID.Equals(buID))
                    Select New Stations With {.ID = s.ID,
                                              .Name = s.Name,
                                              .BullName = s.BullName}).ToList

    End Using
```

Can I do this in a single LINQ statement or do I need to For Each over the collection and load it manually?

**EDIT:**

I have tried the below statement (which might be rubbish) and while it compiles it generates a runtime exception

```
       Dim var = (From s In db.Stations.Where(Function(w) w.BUID.Equals(buID))
                    Select New Stations With {.ID = s.ID,
                                              .Name = s.Name,
                                              .BullName = s.BullName,
                                              .StationMoves = From m In s.Station1
                                                              Select New Stations With {.ID = m.ID,
                                                                                        .Name = m.Name,
                                                                                        .BullName = m.BullName}}).ToList
```

Exception

[image]

Removing the ToList from the above query to prevent the exception it actually evaluates it the blow object.

[image]

Comment: Got it working by iterating over the collections but still wondering if its possible in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a call to `ToList` on your `StationMoves` mapping. Also, if you know the `StationMoves` property is going to be accessed you could eager load it e.g.

```
(From s In db.Stations.Include("StationMoves").Where(Function(w) w.BUID.Equals(buID))
Select New Stations With {.ID = s.ID,
                          .Name = s.Name,
                          .BullName = s.BullName,
                          .StationMoves = s.StationMoves.ToList }).ToList
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Created a runtime exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognise the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List1'. Don't think it would work as the entity object is different from the DTO model object.

Comment: @PhilMurray ah yeah, course. As you need them all to be mapped to a DTO I think your best shout would be to use a tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).